# Java Error: Should be declared in a file named

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to Java and trying to figure out how to solve the following error:

### Error reads

```
CalculatorWithMemory.java:1: class Calculator is public, should be declared 
  in a file named Calculator.java
public class Calculator
```

So my thought was that this means that I have to save 2 different .java files.  However, this being for a class, I only have a provided text block to type my solution into so I cannot save these as .java files.  Any thoughts on a solution would be great.

Thanks in advance!

To Provide all the information. I'm trying to solve for the following.

### Question

The superclass Calculator contains:

- a (protected) double instance variable, accumulator, that contains the current value of the calculator.

write a subclass, CalculatorWithMemory, that contains:

- a double instance variable, memory, initialized to 0
- a method, save, that assigns the value of accumulator to memory
- a method, recall, that assigns the value of memory to accumulator
- a method, clearMemory, that assigns zero to memory
- a method, getMemory, that returns the value stored in memory

Comment: What is the difference between points 3 & 5 in the 2nd list?  If point 3 results in the stored value being returned to the accumulator, what is done with the value returned from point 5?

Answer (score 13):

As the error message implies, if you declare a class as `public`, it needs its own .java file.  If you don't want to do that, then don't define it as `public`.

Comment: Is this to enforce good coding practice, or actually necessary to compilation?

Answer (score 4):

You need to name the file containing the class `Calculator.java`

Answer (score 2):

```
class Something {

}
```

instead of

```
public class Something {

}
```

Comment: This is already covered by the top voted answer from four years ago.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the public class containing main must be same as the file name, in your case the file name should be `Calculator.java`

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when the class name and the filename of a given Java program do not match. For example, say that the following program is saved in a file named Foo.java:

```
public class Bar {     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}



1 error found:
File: Foo.java  [line: 1]
Error: class Bar is public, should be declared in a file named Bar.java
```

Since Foo does not match with Bar, the code doesn't compile. To fix this error, either rename the file or change the class name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than one class in the same file then you are supposed to be writing only one class to be public which has same name as file.

All the other classes you can define as "class abc{}" or using other modifier then public.